# Add SSL-Certificates to Docker/Node

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, ssl

I have to add **SSL** to my **express backend** because of mixed-content errors from my deployment, which runs obviously on https already. After creating a subdomain for my api, I have successfully created let´s encrypt certificates via certbot on my production machine via ssh.

The problem I have is, I **can´t access the certificates from my express server**, because I am building it as a **docker image**. I am searching a **fast way for adding ssl** to my backend. I have found some articles about *nginx*, but as I am new to docker, express etc. I can´t find a good guide on which supports my configuration. Because of that I have tried to keep *nginx* out of the environment, I´m not really sure if this is the way to go..

I am currently **stuck at loading the certificates via volume to the docker image**, which should then be **available in my express config.**

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:14-alpine

ENV NODE_ENV=production SERVER_PORT_HTTP=8080 SERVER_PORT_HTTPS=443

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy working directory from repository
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "./"]

# for reading the ssl certificate created by certbot on host machine 
VOLUME [ "/etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com" ]

# Needed for next step 
COPY prisma ./prisma/

RUN npm install

# Prisma must generate Types bevor starting server
RUN npm i -g @prisma/cli
RUN prisma generate

COPY . .

EXPOSE ${SERVER_PORT_HTTP} ${SERVER_PORT_HTTPS}

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```

**Express app.js**

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV?.trim() === 'production') {
  const https = require('https');
  const fs = require('fs');

  let privateKey = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/privatekey.pem');
  let certificate = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/certificate.pem');

  https.createServer({ key: privateKey, cert: certificate }, app).listen(process.env.SERVER_PORT_HTTPS, function () {
    console.log('Listening on port ' + process.env.SERVER_PORT_HTTPS);
  });
} else {
  app.listen(process.env.SERVER_PORT_HTTP, function () {
    console.log('Listening on port ' + process.env.SERVER_PORT_HTTP);
  });
}
```

**GitHub Workflow**

```
name: GHCR-DigitalOcean

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - "backend/**"

jobs:
  push_to_github_container_registry:
    name: Push to GHCR
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ./backend

    steps:
      # Checkout the Repository
      - name: Checking out the repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Docker Builder
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1

      - name: Logging into GitHub Container Registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          registry: ghcr.io
          username: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
          password: ${{ secrets.CR_PAT }}

      - name: Pushing Image to Github Container Registry
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: ./backend
          version: latest
          file: backend/dockerfile
          push: true
          tags: ghcr.io/${{ github.repository }}:latest

  deploy_to_digital_ocean_dropplet:
    name: Deploy to Digital Ocean Droplet
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: push_to_github_container_registry

    steps:
      - name: Deploy to Digital Ocean droplet via SSH action
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
          key: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}
          port: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
          script: |
            docker kill $(docker ps -q -a)

            docker system prune -a

            docker login https://ghcr.io -u ${{ github.repository_owner }} -p ${{ secrets.CR_PAT }}
 
            docker pull ghcr.io/${{ github.repository }}:latest

            docker run -d -p 80:8080 -p 443:443 -t ghcr.io/${{ github.repository }}:latest
```

Comment: Have you found a solution ? 
In the same situation as you